# Create a cookie in a node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I'm trying in a node.js script. I've try with express/cookie parser & without ...
ATM I'm working in local mode but I will use it on a werbserver.

During all my try, I got any error but the cookie wans't.

My last try (without express/cookie parser) :

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 53134;
const url = require('url');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');   
let express = require('express'); 
let app = express();
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());



http.createServer((req, res) => {
let responseCode = 404;
let content = '404 Error';
const urlObj = url.parse(req.url, true);
let isEclaire = false;

if (urlObj.query.code) {
    const accessCode = urlObj.query.code;
    console.log(`The access code is: ${accessCode}`);
    
    const data = {
        client_id: '805884181811822624',
        client_secret: 'JRSPE0nmRn881Mi9cLC-gMozHKWLQVPT',
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:53134',
        code: accessCode,
        scope: 'identify guilds',
    };

    fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new URLSearchParams(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
    })
        .then(discordRes => discordRes.json())
        .then(info => {
            console.log(info);
            return info;
        })
        .then(info => fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
            headers: {
                authorization: `${info.token_type} ${info.access_token}`,
            },
        }))
        .then(userRes => userRes.json().then(userData => {
            console.log(userData);
            fetch(`https://discord.com/api/guilds/799385448824438824/members/${userData.id}`, {
                headers: {
                    authorization: `Bot ODA1ODg0MTgxODExODIyNjI0.YBhYIQ.h4zLzR7ybBC1uvFSb4iZTH-JVhM`,
                },
            })
            .then(guildRes => guildRes.json().then(guildData => {
                console.log(guildData)
                for(let i = 0; i<guildData.roles.length; i++){
                        console.log(guildData.roles[i]);
                     if(guildData.roles[i] = '804827924217593896') isEclaire = true;
                    }
                console.log(isEclaire)
                    if (isEclaire == true) {
                        console.log('condition is true'); 
                        // Write auth cookie WP
                        res.writeHead(200, {'Set-Cookie': 'cookie', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                        res.writeHead(301, {Location: `http://localhost:53134/?code=${accessCode}`});
                        res.end();
                    } else {
                        console.log('condition is not true');  
                    }// Console will output 'condition not is true'
            }
            ))
        }))
        }

if (urlObj.pathname === '/') {
    responseCode = 200;
    content = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
}

res.writeHead(responseCode, {
    'content-type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
});

res.write(content);
res.end();
})
    .listen(port);
```

I've any preference between using express/cookie parser or not.

Thanks for your thought

Comment: Why do you do `res.writeHead(200, ...)` and then immediately do `res.writeHead(301, ...)`?  Pick one or the other - you can't do both.  You can set multiple headers in one call to `res.writeHead()`, but there can only be one status value and one call to this method.

Comment: Also, you're calling `res.writeHead()` inside a `for` loop which can potentially call it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your server request handler is written, it always calls this:

```
    res.writeHead(responseCode, {
        'content-type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
    });

    res.write(content);
    res.end();
```

And, then sometime later after the `fetch()` call finishes, it may try to set your cookie.  By then, it's far, far, far too late as the response has already been sent.  So, your cookie is never sent.   To fix this, you will have to restructure your code so that if you're going into the branch where you call the `fetch()`, then you are NOT executing the above code at all so that the `fetch()` response handler can send the response it wants to.

---

Also, in the code where you try to set the cookie, you do this:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Set-Cookie': 'cookie', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.writeHead(301, { Location: `http://localhost:53134/?code=${accessCode}` });
res.end();
```

This makes no sense at all.  You can `res.writeHead()` once and only once (you can set multiple header in that one call).  And, you get one and only one status code for the request, not two.  Pick one or the other.